# Bigcommerce Stencil Banners

Tags: bigcommerce

I've created a banner using the Marketing -> Banners control panel, and I entered HTML directly into the content field. In the control panel, everything looks fine... images within an  tag are rendering, so clearly it's reading the HTML properly.

However, when I load the page, all of my HTML tags have been converted to > and < code, so the HTML from the banner doesn't render at all. Furthermore, the entire banner code is wrapped in a

tag that I did not create.

What can I do to fix this?

Comment: I have seen the same issue. Any HTML in the banner box returns a string, which is not rendered as HTML in browser.

Answer (score 1):

I was messing around with this, and figured out it displays the HTML correctly when wrapped in 3 handlebars brackets.

```
{{{banners.top}}}
```

The docs mention escaping HTML [here](https://stencil.bigcommerce.com/docs/custom-handlebars-helpers) in the snippet area using triple brackets, but it is not mentioned this is needed for the Marketing Banners.

Answer (score 0):

Just to confirm that you are using the 'html' editor to enter your code. Correct? Here's a screenshot: http://prntscr.com/bk0xnp

Comment: Confirmed in my case. Valid HTML entered in the HTML editor. Have you had success displaying HTML from a Marketing Banner on a page in Stencil?

Comment: Not Stencil, only in Blueprint.

Comment: Yes, the HTML was entered in the HTML editor, and when viewed in the non-HTML box the images and styles render correctly. It is definitely HTML. However, if you look at the variables in Stencil (using ?debug=bar) you can clearly see that the HTML has been wrapped in a <p> tag and all other < > have been converted.

Comment: Hey Jeff, see my answer below.